# How to make photoshop right sidebar smaller?

Tags: size, width, photoshop, sidebar, osx-elcapitan

I have OS X El Capitan 10.11 and Photoshop CC 2015. My issue is width of right sidebar - I want to make it narrower, because currently is way too wide for me and it makes workspace way too small to work on big files. I'm trying to hold LPM on one side of sidebar and I can make it wider, but can't make it narrower. I'm enclosing screenshot with selected sidebar and current width. How I can make it narrower?

Thank you for help!

[Click here to see screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1IVE.png)

Comment: This is more a http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ question. They will probably know over there.

Answer (score 0):

Each panel has a different set with, for example Color/Kolor is actually thinner than Swatches/próbek. So I imagine the right hand sidebar will not reduced down in width lower than the largest panel. If you drag both Kolor and próbek off the right hand menu and create them as floating tabs you can then scale them as small as possible to see what I mean. They can then be locked back into the right hand menu